# Can't ping from vmware to another pc (request time out)

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, vmware-workstation

I have 2 Computers (pc1 , pc2) pc1 is running under windows 7. (IP: 192.168.1.100) pc2 is running under winXP under vmware workstation9 (IP: 192.168.1.50)

I created a network between them (pc1&pc2) I can Ping from Pc1 to Pc2(vmware) and all packets sent and revived successfully But when i try to ping from Pc2(from vmware) to Pc1 it gives me Request Time Out.

NOTE: ICMP is not blocked in pc1

Comment: Did you disable the firewall or added a firewall exception on the target?

Answer (score 2):

Hope you have selected the "Bridged" network as your adapter settings. Is your Windows firewall disabled or allowed to ping from the problematic machine. Sometimes, the Windows local firewall will block the ping request to timed out.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did everything and still same problem

Comment: Try disabling the local firewall on both the virtual machines and run the following command: netsh firewall set icmpsetting 8 enable

Comment: Also, try this:                                                             1) go to menu VM -> Setting -> select network adapter: NAT

2) got to menu VM -> setting -> select options Tab and select

Guest Isolation : ENABLED, ENABLED and select box : ENABLE VMCI

Comment: Thank you @vembutech .. I did everything you said but still not pinging from vmware ... i can ping only form my pc1(windows7) to pc2(vmware)

Comment: it's worked .. i just disabled the firewall in my bitdefender internet security in win7 and it's worked finally :)

Comment: Disabling firewall on Windows XP fixed this for me!

Answer (score -1):

You are not using workstation pro. In the normal.worstation is no option to run the systems at the same time, so probably by switching you suspend the guest - you have to open two worstations.

Comment: What is a *worstation*?